# Must declare the scalar variable "@ " when field left blank

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a field which while Inserting sometimes I have to keep it blank (Not RequiredField).

I tried the below code and inserted, it gives me error as

> Must declare the scalar variable "@modified_date".

Here is my code below:

```
 if (txtModifieddate.Text == null || txtModifieddate.Text == string.Empty)
 {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@modified_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
 }
 else
 {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@modified_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtModifieddate.Text);
 }
```

Please tell what is going wrong here, even after making condition I m getting the error.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_student_report (student_id,class,attendance,english_subject_marks,math_subject_marks,academic_performance,extra_activities,social_skills,general_health,date_of_record,modified_date,status,active) values (@student_id,@class,@attendance,@english_subject_marks,@math_subject_marks,@academic_performance,@extra_activities,@social_skills,@general_health,@date_of_record,@modified_date,@status,@active)", conn);
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@student_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlstudentname.SelectedValue;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@class", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtClass.Text;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@attendance", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtAttendance.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@english_subject_marks", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtEngMarks.Text;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@math_subject_marks", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtMathsmarks.Text;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@academic_performance", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtAcademicperformance.Text;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@extra_activities", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtExtraActivites.Text;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@social_skills", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtSkills.Text;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@general_health", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtGeneralhealth.Text;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@date_of_record", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtRecorddate.Text;
                    if (txtModifieddate.Text == null || txtModifieddate.Text == string.Empty)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@modified_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@modified_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtModifieddate.Text);
                    }
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = chkStatus.Checked;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = chkActive.Checked;
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Student progress added sucessfully');window.location ='csrstudentprogress.aspx';", true);
                }
            }
```

Comment: does your stored procedure allow `@modified_date` to be null?

Comment: @DLeh: Yes, it allows in the `table`

Comment: post the rest of the command you're sending, we can't tell if you're putting it into a table or a procedure

Comment: can you try setting it to `default(DateTime?)` instead of `DBNull`?

Comment: you mean to say like this `(Datetime)`

Comment: `if (txtModifieddate.Text == null || txtModifieddate.Text == string.Empty)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@modified_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = default(DateTime?);`

Comment: @DLeh: No need of else condition if user adds the `modified_date` ?

Comment: Use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtModifieddate.Text)` instead of `txtModifieddate.Text == null || txtModifieddate.Text == string.Empty`, is easier to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting parameter to command `cmd` instead of `cmd1`

Change it to:

```
//...
if (txtModifieddate.Text == null || txtModifieddate.Text == string.Empty)
{
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@modified_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@modified_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtModifieddate.Text);
}
//...
```

Comment: yes, that was the error. +1 for your concentration. It worked :)